# Extending own classes

Tags: class, extjs4, extend

i am develop an app with several windows. Many windows are similar, so i think write a superclass, and extend it.

I have, the superclass:

```
Ext.define('AM.view.ui.DecoratorAbstract',{
    extend: 'Ext.window.Window',
    alias: 'widget.decoratorAbstract',

    initComponent: function(){
        this.title = this.aTitle;
        this.resizable = this.cfg[0];
        this.closable = this.cfg[1];
        this.minimizable = this.cfg[2];
        //this.items = this.anItem;
        this.callParent(arguments);
    }
});
```

And the subclass:

```
Ext.define('AM.view.ui.DecoratorForm',{
    extend: 'AM.view.ui.DecoratorAbstract',
    alias: 'widget.decoratorForm',

    initComponent: function(){  
        this.callParent();
        this.buttons = [
            { text:'Guardar', action:'save', iconCls: 'ico-save' },
            { text:'Cancelar', action:'cancel', iconCls: 'ico-cancel' }
        ];
    }
});
```

Both classes are included in the Controller:

```
Ext.define('AM.controller.Ui',{
    extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',

    views: [
        'ui.Toolbar',
        'ui.Statusbar',
        'ui.AlertErr',
        'ui.AlertOk',
        'ui.AlertWar',
        'ui.AlertDelete',
        'ui.AlertUndelete',
        'ui.DecoratorAbstract',
        'ui.DecoratorForm',
        'ui.DecoratorGrid'
    ],
    model: [],
    store: [],
});
```

From the Firebug js console i create the subclass:

```
Ext.create('AM.view.ui.DecoratorForm',{cfg:[true,true,true],aTitle: 'Title'}).show();
```

The window is showed but, not the buttons.
Any ideas ?.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things here... First, move `this.callParent()` to the end of your `initComponent`.  This is because the `initComponent` further up the inheritance does something with `this.buttons`, and you are missing out on that by calling `callParent` before setting the buttons.

Next, you really shouldn't use this `cfg` thing that you are passing in.  Just pass in the config parameters that you want to use, and they will be available:

```
Ext.define('AM.view.ui.DecoratorAbstract',{
    extend: 'Ext.window.Window',
    alias: 'widget.decoratorAbstract',

    initComponent: function(){
        this.callParent(arguments);
    }
});

Ext.define('AM.view.ui.DecoratorForm',{
    extend: 'AM.view.ui.DecoratorAbstract',
    alias: 'widget.decoratorForm',

    initComponent: function(){
        this.buttons = [
            { text:'Guardar', action:'save', iconCls: 'ico-save' },
            { text:'Cancelar', action:'cancel', iconCls: 'ico-cancel' }
        ];
        this.callParent();
    }
});

//to instantiate:
Ext.create('AM.view.ui.DecoratorForm',{
    resizable: true,
    closable: true,
    minimizable: true,
    title: 'Title'
}).show();
```

Anytime you are trying to "trick" the component by using something like that `cfg` array, you should probably re-think what you're doing and see if there's a smarter way.

One other thing you should look into using is `Ext.apply()`.  It will save a lot of bytes by changing what you had before into something like this:

```
Ext.apply(this, {
    title: 'my title',
    resizable: cfg[0],
    closable: cfg[1],
    ///...etc...
})
```

Answer (score 0):

What if you move

```
this.callParent(arguments);
```

To the end of initComponent in your DecoratorForm.

Comment: Strictly speaking, `initComponent` doesn't receive any arguments. `this.callParent();` should be sufficient.